# NoMethodError in Users#show - associated object not recognized (NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm getting the error

> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

for this line of code in users/show.html.erb

```
<%= provide(:title, @profile.name) %>
```

I have 'name' defined in the profile model (profile.rb)

```
# return string of first and last name
def name
  "#{first_name} #{last_name}".titleize
end
```

This was working before so I suspect the problem is in the users controller:

```
def show
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 @profile = @user.profile
end
```

Eacher user has one profile. This may also be related to how I've done the "sign up" form, which has profile fields within the user signup form:

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: signup_path, id: "register_form", class: "form-horizontal" ) do |f| %>
          <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
            <div class="form-group">
              <h4>Account information</h4>
              <%= f.label :email, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "john@example.com" %>
              </div>
              <%= f.label :password, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "A-Z,a-z,0-9" %>
              </div>
              <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm password", class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Confirm password" %>
              </div>
            </div>

        <%= f.fields_for :profile do |p| %>

            <div class="form-group">
              <h4>About You</h4>
              <%= p.label :first_name, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                 <%= p.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'First Name' %>
              </div>
            </div>


  <!-- more profile fields here, removed for brevity -->

        <% end %> <!-- fields_for @user.profile -->
      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %> <!-- form_for @user -->
```

Comment: `@user.profile` is nil..

Comment: Is the correct answer. You're either not finding your @user properly, or you haven't assigned them a profile.

Comment: @profile is nil ie profile '@user' doesn't have profile created.

Comment: I'm creating the user and their profile at the same time. Bad idea? Should profile just be a seperate form?

Comment: have you added this in users controller   ( params.require(:user)
      .permit(:email,:password,:password_confirmation, :profile => [:firstname, :lastname]) )

Comment: and  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile in user model, and last_name field is missing from your profile form.

Comment: No I haven't, I'll try that thanks. Is there a good tutorial on this online? (& the form above has a lot of fields taken out. The code would've have been too long otherwise. There's a lot of fields in profile).

Comment: please refer this  links: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html,
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-ruby-on-rails/ruby-on-rails-nested-attributes

Comment: I just wanted to thank you again. Your suggestion worked. :)